# Apps that use CoreMotion and CoreLocation In Background Mode

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app that uses CoreLocation to receive location updates, I have made a timer which checks the location every 5 minutes, stores it and uses it for a graph in the app in the report. I also use CoreMotion that tracks the speed and position of the phone, I can't say more but these components are very crucial to my app.

Question:

1. Is it possible to keep this background mode running as long as the App is in the background mode for intervals of 5 mins, meaning can I receive location and core motion updates?
2. Will this get rejected from apple if I use these components sparringly?
3. Is this even possible to build with the current technology and restrictions from apple?

Comment: so nobody can answer this?